# SQL Oracle, combine and then case

Tags: mysql, oracle, case, concatenation

I am looking to

1) CONCAT 2 Fields
2) use a case statement to leave my concatenated field with only relevant results

Example

```
Colour Item  Quantity
Blue   Socks 1
Brown  Shoes 2
Black  Tie   3
```

I am looking for

```
Concat(Colour,Item)    Quantity
BlueSocks              1
Others                 5
```

I can use `CASE` and `CONCAT`, but can't get the `CASE` to reference the `CONCAT` field.

Comment: Can you reconfirm this has nothing to do mysql? The title says Oracle but you tagged two different database products.

Comment: See if you can be clearer in the question. Especially about what your expected result looks like. At the moment, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why blue socks should be concatenated and not the other rows, but to get the result in your example you could do this:

```
select 
    case 
       when colour = 'Blue' and item = 'Socks' then concat(colour, item) 
       else 'Other' 
    end as Item, 
    sum(quantity) as Quantity
from t -- your table here
group by 
    case 
       when colour = 'Blue' and item = 'Socks' then concat(colour, item) 
       else 'Other' 
    end
```

If you don't want to repeat the case expression in the select and group by clauses you could wrap it in a derived table or common table expression.